# MPMoviePlayerController & iPhone OS4 issues

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've been developing an iPhone using xcode 3.2.2 and using 3.O as my base sdk. Recently I upgrade xcode to the latest version.

As I understand from reading posts on here I've found out if I set my base sdk to 4.0 and my development target to Os 3.0 my app will run on devices running Os 3.0 and upwards.

I've been using MPMoviePlayerController to play movies which isn't available on 4.0 so I updated my code to use MPMoviePlayerViewController this works on a 4.0 device but doesn't on a 3.1.2 device.

I found out yesterday If I check the device versions I can use either MPMoviePlayerController or MPMoviePlayerViewController depending on what firmware the device is running.
So now I can play movies that play on both my devices

Here my problem...

In the 4.0 code using MPMoviePlayerViewController I can hide the controls using MPMovieControlStyleNone and when a MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification is trigger I set the style to MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen so the playback control are hidden until the user taps the device.

But when I use MPMoviePlayerController for device using 3.0 setting the controlStyle causes my app to crash. I cannot use movieControlStyle as it deprecated. The same issue also applies to the MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification.

So anyone have any idea how I set the style and the notification?

thanks in advance

Scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ([movie respondsToSelector:@selector(setControlStyle:)]) {
    movie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
} else {
    movie.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;
}
```

You still have to use `movieControlMode` on devices where no alternative exists.